# how i can get the list of all T-SQL reserved keywords in c# a program

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to have a list of all t-sql reserved keywords at run time in a C# program.

```
bool iskeyword = IsSqlReservedKeyword("string");
```

or

```
list<string> ReservedKeywordList = new list<string>();

ReservedKeywordList = GetSQLReservedKeywords();
```

Like in C# there is a method `IsValidIdentifier("string")`. Is there a similar method for SQL types?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: what about the SQL's version?

Comment: like in c# there is a method "IsValidIdentifier("string")", there should be similar method for SQL types.

Comment: I'm extremely disappointed by the harshness shown by some of the community members here...Leon has a problem and he asked if there's a direct solution for that. People should reply whether or not it's feasible and not be too quick with the downvote button. It's not something which is not related to technology, it's just a bit unintuitive...

Answer (score 3):

All reserved (and potentially reserved ones in the future) keywords are [listed on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). You need to set up a property which returns this list of words yourself. A bit iffy but you need to do it only once.

I would probably write a little Perl or Python script to parse that page and create the property for me. Might take longer but it's more fun than doing it manually plus one might learn something in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list in C# (you cand find the list here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql):

```
List<string> reservedKeywords = new List<string>()
{
    { "ADD" },
    { "EXTERNAL" },
    { "PROCEDURE" },
    { "ALL" },
    { "FETCH" },
    { "PUBLIC" },
    { "ALTER" },
    { "FILE" },
    { "RAISERROR" },
    { "AND" },
    { "FILLFACTOR" },
    { "READ" },
    { "ANY" },
    { "FOR" },
    { "READTEXT" },
    { "AS" },
    { "FOREIGN" },
    { "RECONFIGURE" },
    { "ASC" },
    { "FREETEXT" },
    { "REFERENCES" },
    { "AUTHORIZATION" },
    { "FREETEXTTABLE" },
    { "REPLICATION" },
    { "BACKUP" },
    { "FROM" },
    { "RESTORE" },
    { "BEGIN" },
    { "FULL" },
    { "RESTRICT" },
    { "BETWEEN" },
    { "FUNCTION" },
    { "RETURN" },
    { "BREAK" },
    { "GOTO" },
    { "REVERT" },
    { "BROWSE" },
    { "GRANT" },
    { "REVOKE" },
    { "BULK" },
    { "GROUP" },
    { "RIGHT" },
    { "BY" },
    { "HAVING" },
    { "ROLLBACK" },
    { "CASCADE" },
    { "HOLDLOCK" },
    { "ROWCOUNT" },
    { "CASE" },
    { "IDENTITY" },
    { "ROWGUIDCOL" },
    { "CHECK" },
    { "IDENTITY_INSERT" },
    { "RULE" },
    { "CHECKPOINT" },
    { "IDENTITYCOL" },
    { "SAVE" },
    { "CLOSE" },
    { "IF" },
    { "SCHEMA" },
    { "CLUSTERED" },
    { "IN" },
    { "SECURITYAUDIT" },
    { "COALESCE" },
    { "INDEX" },
    { "SELECT" },
    { "COLLATE" },
    { "INNER" },
    { "SEMANTICKEYPHRASETABLE" },
    { "COLUMN" },
    { "INSERT" },
    { "SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE" },
    { "COMMIT" },
    { "INTERSECT" },
    { "SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE" },
    { "COMPUTE" },
    { "INTO" },
    { "SESSION_USER" },
    { "CONSTRAINT" },
    { "IS" },
    { "SET" },
    { "CONTAINS" },
    { "JOIN" },
    { "SETUSER" },
    { "CONTAINSTABLE" },
    { "KEY" },
    { "SHUTDOWN" },
    { "CONTINUE" },
    { "KILL" },
    { "SOME" },
    { "CONVERT" },
    { "LEFT" },
    { "STATISTICS" },
    { "CREATE" },
    { "LIKE" },
    { "SYSTEM_USER" },
    { "CROSS" },
    { "LINENO" },
    { "TABLE" },
    { "CURRENT" },
    { "LOAD" },
    { "TABLESAMPLE" },
    { "CURRENT_DATE" },
    { "MERGE" },
    { "TEXTSIZE" },
    { "CURRENT_TIME" },
    { "NATIONAL" },
    { "THEN" },
    { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" },
    { "NOCHECK" },
    { "TO" },
    { "CURRENT_USER" },
    { "NONCLUSTERED" },
    { "TOP" },
    { "CURSOR" },
    { "NOT" },
    { "TRAN" },
    { "DATABASE" },
    { "NULL" },
    { "TRANSACTION" },
    { "DBCC" },
    { "NULLIF" },
    { "TRIGGER" },
    { "DEALLOCATE" },
    { "OF" },
    { "TRUNCATE" },
    { "DECLARE" },
    { "OFF" },
    { "TRY_CONVERT" },
    { "DEFAULT" },
    { "OFFSETS" },
    { "TSEQUAL" },
    { "DELETE" },
    { "ON" },
    { "UNION" },
    { "DENY" },
    { "OPEN" },
    { "UNIQUE" },
    { "DESC" },
    { "OPENDATASOURCE" },
    { "UNPIVOT" },
    { "DISK" },
    { "OPENQUERY" },
    { "UPDATE" },
    { "DISTINCT" },
    { "OPENROWSET" },
    { "UPDATETEXT" },
    { "DISTRIBUTED" },
    { "OPENXML" },
    { "USE" },
    { "DOUBLE" },
    { "OPTION" },
    { "USER" },
    { "DROP" },
    { "OR" },
    { "VALUES" },
    { "DUMP" },
    { "ORDER" },
    { "VARYING" },
    { "ELSE" },
    { "OUTER" },
    { "VIEW" },
    { "END" },
    { "OVER" },
    { "WAITFOR" },
    { "ERRLVL" },
    { "PERCENT" },
    { "WHEN" },
    { "ESCAPE" },
    { "PIVOT" },
    { "WHERE" },
    { "EXCEPT" },
    { "PLAN" },
    { "WHILE" },
    { "EXEC" },
    { "PRECISION" },
    { "WITH" },
    { "EXECUTE" },
    { "PRIMARY" },
    { "WITHIN GROUP" },
    { "EXISTS" },
    { "PRINT" },
    { "WRITETEXT" },
    { "EXIT" },
    { "PROC" },
    { "RELEASE" }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a list and populate this list by putting all the strings in that list. You can pick the strings from the path given by Michael. Something like:

```
private List<String> CreateSQLReservedKeywordList()
{
  List<String> list = new List<String>();
  list.Add("Exists");
  list.Add("RaiseError");
  ...
}
```

For advanced purposes, you can create an excel or CSV and populate the list from these files.

Comment: i have done this but the count of reserved keywords keep increasing.

Comment: If you mean that new keywords are getting added then I'd say that's a given. You can't restrict that but to handle that you can keep all the keywords in a csv and load that file. This way you don't need to change your code if the keywords change...

Comment: Thanks for your support Sidharth, there is a way for that by using Table type object and a Property "QuotedIdentifierStatus". i was looking for something like that. due to some restrictions i can't use csv files.

Comment: Cool, no problem. The QuotedIdentifierStatus thing is nice. :)